# How to make python script to run at specific time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my script, it takes screenshots after 5 seconds and stores it into a png file with timestamp as its name.
I want this script to run between 9am to 5pm everyday so i could get screenshot f every activity done between 9 to 5 every day.

```
import pyautogui
import time
for i in range(4):
    # Take screensot
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    #Name the file with data and time
    ts = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    filename = "screenshot"
    filename += str(ts)
    filename += ".png"
    # Save the image
    pic.save('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Frankiii\{}'.format(filename)) 
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: use the windows task scheduler to schedule the script
Or you could use the scheduler library to make the process run in the background

Comment: You could also use `cron` and schedule it.

Comment: You are going to quickly fill up your hard drive doing this.

Comment: Great spy tool - just the less and less space on the HD is limiting its usefullness ... and having to sieve through 8*60*12 = 5780 pictures each day to find the gems: banking information, shady frequented websites, work on code or private data that is confidential, ...

Comment: Seriously. If you want screenshots every 5 seconds, you may as well just go with a low frame rate video. But even that you shouldn't do, for all the same reasons.

Comment: i am gonna increase the time between two screenshot intervals, like for 15 min,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could do it.

```
import schedule

def start():
    print("{} Start the job".format(datetime.datetime.now()))

def stop():
    print("{} Time's up!!!".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    sys.exit()

schedule.every().day.at("09:00").do(start)
schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(stop)
```

Comment: @sanketgadge If this helped you, and if you think this is the right answer for the question you have asked, please make sure to accept the answer for further references.

Comment: yeah sure,  i am gonna need lot of help to build my things, hope this community will help me out.